# Background fetch after a long time interval in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, background-process

The default background fetch interval is `3 min` in iOS 7 or later but I want to background fetch after a `2 hours` for news update.

I tried too many methods like i.e.

1. Use the `NSTimer`
2. `Sleep` the thread
3. Set minimum `background fetch internal`

After all hard work the result is

1. After Some time application `crash`
2. After Some time when application come in `foreground` then news update
3. After Some time `no new data update`

I have tried this code:

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {    
     __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskID=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

       NSLog(@"background task expiration handler called");
       NSLog(@"Task ID is:%lu",(unsigned long)taskID);

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endBackgroundTask:taskID];
   }];

    if(taskID==UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to start background task");
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"Start Background task with %f seconds remaining",[[UIApplication sharedApplication]backgroundTimeRemaining ]);

        [self download];
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:25];
        NSLog(@"Finishing Background task with %f seconds remaining",[[UIApplication sharedApplication]backgroundTimeRemaining ]);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endBackgroundTask:taskID];
    });
}


-(void)download
{
    ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSDate *fetchStart=[NSDate date];
    [viewController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
        viewController.i++;
        if(viewController.i<5)
        {
            [self download];
        }
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)result);
    }];

    NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
    NSLog(@"Background Fetch Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);


}
```

> I used the `recursion` to update five news channels. My device not
>   connected to `X-Code`. My background fetch is on in capabilities.

Comment: You seem to be a little confused. You have up to 3 minutes of background execution time, which you can access via the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method, but you should only use this method of you need to perform some work when your app is activated in the background by some event or from the `didEnterBackground` delegate method.  If you use background fetch then iOS will periodically call `fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler`. You don't  have any control over how often iOS calls this method, but it will use the value you supply to the completion handler to tune its behaviour

Comment: Also you should move your download method out of your view controller. If your app is launched in the background for background fetch there is a good chance that it won't have a view controller

Comment: Is timer working in background?

Comment: If you have a long running task, then yes, for up to 3 minutes, but otherwise no

Comment: any alternate solution for more than 3 minutes?

Comment: You have to use one of the supported background modes. For your application that is background fetch, but you can't control exactly when you will get called. iOS manages it